# Magento 2 products are not being added to cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, addtocart

Does anyone know why this would be happening. My SSL cert is not installed correctly, can this be an issue? If not what can it be? I am taken to the cart page but it's empty.

Comment: did you checked logs?

Comment: Use ip instead of localhost to install magento 2.

Comment: Nothing in the logs. @Rizwan